# How to find numbers in string and replace them with a dom object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initial have:

```
var e.name = 'Mg2(OH)3';
```

Need to have:

```
var sub = '<p>Mg<span class="sub">2</span>(OH)<span class="sub">3</span</p>';
```

Need to add before and after number the span. 
How to do that with jQuery or on native javascript?

Comment: nothing to do with jquery. that's just string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.replace` method, no jQuery needed.

```
var str = 'Mg2(OH)3';
str = '<p>' + str.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="sub">$1</span>') + '</p>';
console.log(str); // returns: <p>Mg<span class="sub">2</span>(OH)<span class="sub">3</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also adding the enclosing paragraph tags:

```js
var e = {};

e.name = 'Mg2(OH)3';

var sub = '<p>Mg<span class="sub">2</span>(OH)<span class="sub">3</span></p>';

e.name = '<p>' + e.name.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="sub">$1</span>') + '</p>';

console.log(sub);

console.log(e.name);
```